# Apache Superset not available from my browser

Tags: python-venv, apache-superset, centos8

After following the installation instructions referenced at https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch, I'm not able to see the app at the ip number/server port in my win 10 web browser. How do I make it work at the right ip address?

I've installed it under venv running on a CentOS 8 VM on my win 10 laptop. I'm using the NAT network adapter and I can can use putty and the CentOS 8 cockpit app is available on port 9090.

**Currently it says it's running at 127.0.0.1:8089:**

```
(venv) /root>superset run -p 8089 --with-threads --reload --debugger
logging was configured successfully
2021-08-04 15:35:48,492:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2021-08-04 15:35:48,505:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
/root/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py:201: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
  warnings.warn(
No PIL installation found
2021-08-04 15:35:48,722:INFO:superset.utils.screenshots:No PIL installation found
 * Serving Flask app "superset" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2021-08-04 15:35:50,007:INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8089/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

**netstat shows port 8089 open for 127.0.0.1, but not the VM's ip number. nmap shows the port closed.**

```
/root>netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8089          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4247/python3
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      944/sshd
/root>nmap 192.168.42.130
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-04 15:45 PDT
Nmap scan report for kevinsAppServer (192.168.42.130)
Host is up (0.000015s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.73 seconds
/root>nmap -p 8089 192.168.42.130
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-04 15:45 PDT
Nmap scan report for kevinsAppServer (192.168.42.130)
Host is up (0.000067s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8089/tcp closed unknown
```

I think it should work if i can get the port opened on my server's IP number, unless there's something I did wrong..

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding the -h option for the superset run command, which I found when running the superset run --help at the server command line. So now this command works:

superset run -h my.i.p.adddress -p 8089 --with-threads --reload --debugger

In my case I also had to open port 8089 on the CentOS firewall.